# AWS: Resource policy for an AWS HTTPS API Gateway to restirct access to specific IP's

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

Recently AWS released HTTPS based API Gateway(Not the REST one). We use Terraform to manage the AWS resources and we have a service where we create the AWS HTTPS API Gateway resource, there was a security concern that we were allowing any IP/system to invoke the API, hence we planned to add a policy (Resource Policy) to restrict access to only specific IP's. It was easy to achieve this for REST API Gateway as we have *aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy* resource to create and attach the policy to the Gateway through Terraform, but the same could not be achieved for HTTPS API Gateway. We use *aws_apigatewayv2_api* to create an HTTPS Gateway resource, but couldn't find a resource to atatch a policy or neither it has an option to specify policy while creating the Gateway itself. Any help here would be very much appreciated to know how to attach a policy to HTTPS based API. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Its good practice to accept helpful answers as they limit number of duplicate questions, remove questions from [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services?tab=Unanswered) list and indicate to future readers that the answers given are actually helpful for the given problem.

Comment: Sure, will do that as a practise. Thank you.

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case here but it sounds like CORS may work for what you are trying to achieve? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource policies are **not supported** in HTTP API. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html):

[image]

Thus if you want to restrict API to some specific IP addresses using the API resource policies you have to use REST API.

Comment: Thank you Marcin for the response. You mean to use REST instead of HTTPS to restrict IP based, right?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Just thought to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

While the resource policies are not supported this can be accomplished via a custom authorizer Lambda function. I'm sure there will be a better way at a later date but for now you could do something like this:

```
module.exports.authorizer = async(event, context) => {
     
  let response = {
      "isAuthorized": false,
  };

  const allowedIps = ["x.x.x.x"];
  
  if (allowedIps.includes(event.headers["x-forwarded-for"])) {
      response.isAuthorized = true;
  }
  
  console.log(response);
  
  return response;
}
```

I realize this isn't the most elegant solution but it would work. This is assuming a simple authorizer response and payload format version 2.0. Your identitysource would be $request.header.x-forwarded-for. I mention this because all requests get denied if that header isn't present. If you're testing locally you'll need to add that header to your curl/insomnia/postman call. You could augment the code pretty easily to deal with CIDRs if you like

[AWS Lambda Authorizer Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html)